# Auto Adjust DIV content in browser - Rescale if it's necessary

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to show a lot of items, DIV class='box', in the browser. For that, I would like to auto adjust the number of elements according to the width of the windows browser. These elements also rescale if it's necessary.

The width of the elements it's the same. I'm using the Bootstrap framework for do it.

I would like this result:

[image]

[image]

According to the size of the browser, auto adjust elements and scale.

```css
body{
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

/*          BOX PRINCIPAL        */

.box{
  margin: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 4px solid #004259;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*          IMAGE                */

.img-prod{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align: center;

  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

/*          ON HOVER             */

.box:hover{
  border: 4px solid #FDE1AE;
}

/*
.box:hover .text-link{
  color: #FDE1AE !important;
}
.box:hover .text-edicio{
  color: #FDE1AE !important;
}
*/

.box:hover .img-prod {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

/*            BOX-TEXT             */

.box-text{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( rgba(255,0,0,0), #004259);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( rgba(255,0,0,0), #004259);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( rgba(255,0,0,0), #004259);
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255,0,0,0), #004259);
  bottom: 45%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.box-text span{
   color: #f8f8f8;
}
.text{
  position: absolute;
  width: 96%;
  left: 3%;
  bottom: 10%;
}
.text-codi{
  font-size: small;
}
.text-descripcio{
  font-size: medium;
}
.text-edicio{
  color: #99B3BD !important;
  font-size: x-small;
}
.text-link{
  color: #f8f8f8 !important;
}
.text-link:hover,
.text-link:focus{
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*          CHECK CARD           */

.checkbox {
  bottom: 97%;
  left: 3%;
}

/*          BUTTON CARD           */

.btn-estat{
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 300px;
  left: 87%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #73CBB0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class='row'>  <!-- width would be 100% of img-grid width -->

    <?php
      $i = 0;
      while ($i < 20){ ?>

        <div class='col-md-3'>
          <div class="box">
            <a class="text-link" href='#'>
                <img class="img-prod" src="http://placeimg.com/440/680/any" />
            </a>

            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check1" />

            <button type="submit" class="btn-estat">
                <i class='material-icons' style='font-size: 20px;'>done</i>
            </button>

            <div class="box-text">
                <span class='text'>
                  <span class="text-codi">
                      <a class="text-link" href='#'>11111</a>
                  </span><br/>
                  <span class="text-descripcio">
                      <a class="text-link" href='#'>TEXT EXAMPLE</a>
                  </span><br />
                </span>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      <?php
          $i++;
      } ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

I know to apply a fixed number of elements by row but I don't know to do to show the elements according to size.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap already it's simply a case of applying the right classes to the elements. Check their documentation for `col-sm-*` and `col-md-*` etc

Comment: I've done test. The col-sm-* and col-md-* it's the number of cols according the resolution of the output device but in this case I don't want to put a fixed number of columns I would like to calculate according the size.

Comment: why don't you just use `display:inline-block` on the items then ? without bootstrap .https://jsfiddle.net/g3pj1do6/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use any of the popular jquery masonry plugins:

https://masonry.desandro.com/

https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

http://salvattore.com/

Comment: Ohh! masonry plugin it's a best option

Comment: You know you can accept this as the answer, right? Click the ✔ under the arrows. Also check your profile and go trough your old questions and mark the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution would be to use flexbox:

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.thumbnail {
  flex: 0 0 100px; /* or any other fixed width */
}
```

Here's very good introduction to flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**EDIT:**
here's jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ex017ok1/

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the grid system that's easy!

At present you have given the boxes a class of col-md-3. So you should get 4 columns on desktop. As you are only using one row adding the class col-sm-4 would ensure that you get 3 columns on a tablet. If you want to always show say 4 columns regardless of viewport then try col-xs-3

If you want the space like in the top image then you could create an offset.

row
   --- col-sm-10 col-offset-sm-1
       --- row
           --- divs with col-xs-3

Comment: I don't know to show always 4 columns I want to put in the screen the numbers of elements according the size of the browser. I put the col-md3 only for code example and my testing.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your question. If you want to control the number of elements according to screen width then columns using bootstrap or similar is what you are after? Alternatively ditch bootstrap grid and simply change your layout yourself using mediaqueries? As someone else mentioned perhaps masonry.js is the way to go?